# Why isn't my SSH tunnel working?

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

The SVN server at my work has been moved to a different machine. This wouldn't present a problem except that the firewall rules have not been set up properly and I'm unable to connect to the new server on the SVN Server port.

This should also be a trivial problem, however the processing time for a firewall change request is over 2 weeks.

I am able to SSH to the SVN server. Inside the Putty session I am able to wget pages from the SVN server, so I know my user/pass is ok and the server is up and running.

So I figured I'd set up an SSH tunnel to get me by in the meantime. I followed the instructions at http://www.anapnea.net/tut_putty_tunneling.php but am getting an error "Unable to Connect" when attempting to hit the URL from the browser.

How can I diagnose what is going wrong? The putty logs don't seem to show anything useful. I have verified that TCP Forwarding and X11 Forwarding are enabled in sshd_config.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Guide you follow sets up a socks proxy (dynamic). What you probably want is Local Forwarding (local). You tunnel from localhost:Port to destination:Port and point your svn client to localhost:Port.

Comment: I think you want to connect to a specif port on remote server which is not accessible due to firewall. In this case you need local forwarding as suggested in above comment. in local forwarding, you will connect to that specific port on you local desktop, and open a ssh tunnel which will route the traffic to destination server over ssh.

Comment: I tried using local forwarding and that doesn't work for me either. =( Is there any way to debug this stuff? The log have anything that looks like tunnel information in it.

Comment: I take it back. Local forwarding works. I still don't understand why dynamic forwarding does not, but this is good enough.